# How to Avoid Race Condition in FragmentManager?

Tags: android, race-condition, android-dialogfragment, fragmentmanager, kotlin-sharedflow

My goal is to allow only one single instance of the same dialog fragment in the fragment stack.

The current trigger condition is coming from a SharedFlow and can be triggered as often as `7ms` apart between values.

Here's what I have tried:

1. Placing the code in a `synchronized` block
2. Checking whether existing fragment is in the stack by calling `fm.findFragmentByTag`

However, both the conditions are not enough to prevent the fragment from adding multiple times to the fragmentManager.

I tried with `dialogFragment.showNow(fm, tag)` but it's unstable and it's crashing

Appreciate for any helps.

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  viewModel.someSharedFlow
    .flowWithLifecycle(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle)
    .onEach { showMyFragmentDialog() }
    .launchIn(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope)
}

private fun showMyFragmentDialog() {
  synchronized(childFragmentManager) {
    if (childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(MyFragment.TAG) == null) {
      MyFragment.newInstance(fuelTypes)
        .show(childFragmentManager, MyFragment.TAG)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resorted with coroutine for now. Not ideal but at least it's working.

```kotlin
private var myLaunchJob: Job? = null
private fun showMyFragmentDialog() {
  if (myLaunchJob?.isActive == true) return
  myLaunchJob = viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    if (childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(MyFragment.TAG) == null) {
      MyFragment.newInstance(fuelTypes)
        .show(childFragmentManager, MyFragment.TAG)
    }
    // Act as debouncer
    delay(1000)
  }
}
```